# Not getting the array on JSON

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json

*Hello I am trying to break down JSON data*

```
 ** {
    "message": "gradeExam.php",
    "id": "171",
    "student_id": "dfd",
    "questions": [{
          "question_id": "0",
          "student_input": "def doubly_"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "1",
          "student_input": "asd"
        }
    ]
}**
```

*using PHP*

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$_POST = json_decode($json, true);

$input = $_POST["questions"];
foreach($input as $questions)
{
$quest_id[] = $questions["question_id"];
$student_input[] = $questions["student_input"];
}
echo $quest_id;
echo $student_input;
```

*BUT keep getting a response of..* **ArrayArrayArray[]**

I am trying loop and get the data of question_id: 0, student_input: def doubly_, question_id: 1, student_input: asd.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't echo an array, use `var_dump($quest_id, $student_input);`

Comment: array(2) {
[0]=>
string(1) "0"
[1]=>
string(1) "1"
}
array(2) {
[0]=>
string(11) "def doubly_"
[1]=>
string(3) "asd"
} ---this is what i get in return

Comment: Isn't that what you want? The first is an array of question IDs, the second is an array of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that you have done is correct except these 2 lines.

```
echo $quest_id;
echo $student_input;
```

As $quest_id and $student_input are arrays we cannot use the echo function. Instead, you can use the print_r function as below

```
print_r($quest_id);
print_r($student_input);
```